# MSSQL Insert n number of rows based on a number in the NoOfRows field into another table

Tags: sql-server

How will I go about inserting n number of rows based on the NoOfRows field into another table(B).

```
Table A Source Table
    ID  | NoOfRows 
    ---------
    1   |    3
    2   |    2

Table B Created/Destination table
    ID  | enabled
    ---------
    1   |    true
    1   |    true
    1   |    true
    2   |    true
    2   |    true
```

Enabled is just a field that will always be set to true

Comment: And now we have to guess what is N and the destination table in your question?

Comment: My Apologies my explination was poor. Table A is my source and table B my destination. so table b needs to have 3 rows created based on the number in NoOfRows of table A

Comment: I'm curious as to why you would wan't to do this given that the destination table is not in normal form?

Answer (score 0):

One method uses a table of numbers.  Here is one approach that works, unless you have really high counts:

```
with n as (
      select row_number() over (order by (select null)) as n
      from master..spt_values
     )
select id, 1 as enabled
from a join
     n
     on n.n <= a.count;
```

If you have another source of sequential numbers in your environment, then you can use that.

Also, I use "1" for "true"; SQL Server does not have a boolean type.

Comment: My Apologies my explination was poor. Table A is my source and table B my destination. so table b needs to have 3 rows created based on the number in NoOfRows of table A

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO TableA (ID , [Count])
SELECT ID , COUNT(*) 
FROM TableB
WHERE [enabled] = 'true'
GROUP BY ID
```

Comment: My Apologies my explination was poor. Table A is my source and table B my destination. so table b needs to have 3 rows created based on the number in NoOfRows of table A